# Python program error

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, and I tried to make a python program. Here it is:

```
import time
gravity = 0
space = 0

print "Welcome to the 'Find out who is in space' program"

person_messy = raw_input("Enter a name:")

person = person_messy.lower()

if len(person) < 5:
    print "Make sure you put the first AND last name"
else:
    space = 1
    print "Searching database....."

if person == "oleg kotov" or "mike hopkins" or "sergey ryazanskiy" or "fyodor yurchikhin" or "karen nyberg" or "luca permitano":
    gravity = 1
else:
    gravity = 0

time.sleep(1)

if space == 1:
    print "loading..."

time.sleep(1)

if space == 1:
    print "loading..."

time.sleep(1)

if space == 1:
    print  "loading..."

if gravity == 1:
    print person + "is in space!"
else:
    print "You and " + person + "are on the same planet."
```

this is the error I got:

> Internal error: ReferenceError: _select is not defined

Comment: Are you using an online Python interpreter, by any chance?

Comment: When exactly did you get the error?

Comment: Can you describe your environment? This is not normal behavior.

Comment: Please:  describe what your program's expected behavior is and provide the full stack trace and your environment details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on similar code... You can't use time.sleep or it gives this. I don't know why, but that fixed my code(not using time.sleep)